how i transfer my spl token by js
Hello i need to write a program that transfer token from my wallet to another wallet i wrote here is code
const {clusterApiUrl, Connection, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, PublicKey} =  require('@solana/web3.js');
const  {createMint, getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, mintTo, transfer} = require('@solana/spl-token');
const bs58 = require("bs58");
(async () => {
    // Connect to cluster
    const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
    const DEMO_WALLET_SECRET_KEY = new bs58.decode("<My Private Key>");

    const fromWallet =  Keypair.fromSecretKey(DEMO_WALLET_SECRET_KEY);;
     
    const toWallet = new PublicKey('<Destination Wallet Address>');

    // Create new token mint
   
    const mint = new PublicKey('<My Mint Account Address');
   
   // Get the token account of the fromWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
        const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            connection,
            fromWallet,
            mint,
            fromWallet.publicKey
        );
    console.log(fromTokenAccount);
    //     // Get the token account of the toWallet address, and if it does not exist, create it
        const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection, fromWallet, mint, toWallet);
    
    
        // Transfer the new token to the "toTokenAccount" we just created
        signature = await transfer(
            connection,
            fromWallet,
            fromTokenAccount.address,
            toTokenAccount.address,
            fromWallet.publicKey,
            100000000
        );
    })();

it works fine but for a coin that i made according to this document
and it doesn't works for coin i made according to official document !
when i use mint address of that coin i get bellow error

please help me and tell my why i have this problem because i would like to make my token according to official document,thanks.

The Official guide that you provided uses the Token extensions program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA to mint the token.
Change the programId where neccessary to point to it TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
e.g in the transfer TX
   let signature = await transfer(
            connection,
            fromWallet,
            fromTokenAccount.address,
            toTokenAccount.address,
            fromWallet.publicKey,
            100000000,
            [],
            {},
            new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
        );

and the get or create function
let toTokenAccount = await (
        await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
            conn,
            signer,
            mint,
            signer.publicKey,
            false,
            "finalized",
            {},
            new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
        )
    ).address;


i added but still have that problem

and i get error from fromTokenAccount  not transfer

I fond out know error is from both
